# Problem on Windows 7 using Image.FromStream to open cmyk+alpha tiff file

Tags: .net, windows-7, gdi+, tiff

I'm having a problem running the following code om Windows 7 x86
when creating an Image from a lzw encoded cmyk + alpha TIFF file.

The FromStream call throws a System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not validRunning 
When I run the code on Vista or Server 2008 (both x86 and x64 bit) it just works.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
.
.
.        
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
  using (Image image = Image.FromStream(stream, false, false))
  {
    // Do something with the image
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was working with previous versions of Windows, it might be a bug in Win7... You should probably file a bug at Microsoft Connect